# Redeploy Openshift Application when Docker Hub Image Changes?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, dockerhub

Is there a way to trigger a re-deploy when I push an image to docker hub? I used S2I to build an image, put it up on docker hub, and did a deployment from there. How can I trigger a new deployment when I push a new image to docker hub?

Perhaps there is a better way? I created a wildfly image with the changes to the standalone.xml I needed. Then I used S2I to build my local source into a runnable wildfly application image, which is what I pushed and deployed. I'm trying to get around having to go through a github repository.

I'm thinking I could create an application with the customer wildfly image that I created and use the direct from IDE option to the application, but what if I want to use the command line?

Answer (score 2):

You can set a `scheduled` flag on the image stream to have a remote registry periodically polled. This will only work though if the OpenShift cluster has been configured globally to allow that. If using OpenShift Online I don't believe that feature is enabled.

- https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/latest/dev_guide/managing_images.html#importing-tag-and-image-metadata

If you want to avoid using a Git repository, you can use a binary input build instead. This allows you to push files direct from your local computer. This means you can compile binary artifacts locally and push them into the S2I build done by OpenShift.

- https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/latest/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#binary-source

Comment: It's openshift online, so no polling I guess, plus I think it's a lame option. The binary image I looked interesting, but I think I need a local file to use, and I haven't figured out how to get my S2I image to an actual file. Docker hub has a webhook so I'm surprised that there isn't a webhook in the openshift image source configuration. I saw that the IDE direct puts the .war file into the deployment, so I think that's what I'm ultimately trying to do. Still kind of new to all this. Thanks.

Comment: Yeh, I am talking about use the WAR file as binary input into S2I build process. If you still want to build the image itself locally, you can do that. You then just need to login to the OpenShift internal registry and push your image direct into it. Doing that will trigger re-deployments as soon as push happens. https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/latest/dev_guide/managing_images.html#accessing-the-internal-registry From memory if you lookup image stream details in web console it will give you details for registry for logging in.